# Google Mobile Ad issue with Web Trends SDK on iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, google-dfp, ios8.4, webtrends

We have iOS app which is already integrated Web Trends SDK in our  iOS app, Now we are facing strange problem.  
GoogleMobileAds does not work after integration with iOS app although it works if we remove Web Trends SDK.  Does GoogleMobileAds is not compatible with Web Trends SDK?
 I am using following code to show google banner ad.

```
adView = DFPBannerView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50))
adView.adUnitID = "/6499/example/banner"
adView.rootViewController = self;
adView.rootViewController = self;
let adrequest = DFPRequest()
adView.loadRequest(adrequest)
```

We are getting logs in console as below, May be helpful for you.

```
2015-09-17 12:15:26.275 WebTrendsDemo[270:13293] -[GADAdView previewItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157ef560
2015-09-17 12:15:26.276 WebTrendsDemo[270:13293] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[GADAdView previewItem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x157ef560
```

I have tested it by creating several demo apps but getting same result for Web Trend SDK with Google Ad, No success.
 
If I remove Web Trend SDK then Google Ad start works as I already mention above. You can check it by creating a demo app using Web Trend SDK with Google Ad.
 
If you successfully implement Web Trend SDK with Google Ad  by creating a demo app then please share it with me .
 
 
Thanks

Comment: I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue in Web Trends SDK version 3.0.4.Use Web Trends SDK version 3.0.6. Web Trends resolved the issue in current iOS WT SDK version. I am able to get Google Mobile Ad in Web Trends current SDK version(3.0.6).